# Formal Imperative of “sein” — “Sein” or “Seien”?

Tags: grammaticality, politeness, imperative

If I’m not mistaken, the formal imperative reads like this:

> <Infinitive Verb> + Sie + … ( + bitte).

In case of the verb *sein* the infinitive is just *sein* itself. So on what grounds this sentence is correct?

> Seien Sie vorsichtig.

I did not figure it out after a little lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does indeed look like an exception. I am not aware of any other verbs where the imperative polite form does not match the infinitive (but I may just not have thought of it). In any case, the polite *(Sie*-form) imperative of *sein* is indeed *seien.*

[Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-V/Texte/Imper3.html?lang=en) claims that there are only two imperatives: singular and plural. For *sein,* the singular imperative would be *sei* and the plural one *seid.* They continue to say that to make a polite request, one must resort to conjunctive I of the third person plural (capitalised to be *Sie).* Since they state no exceptions, it seems that ‘seien Sie’ can be perfectly rationalised with this rule. Again, I am not aware of any other verb whose conjunctive I form in third person plural does not match its infinitive.

Canoo.net’s definition does suffer from the fact that an imperative statement comes with a different word order, but it seems consistend and rational.

Comment: Ahh, once more *sein* proves to be the exception to every rule. Most irregular word there is, in every language that has it.

Answer (score 2):

The infinitive "sein" and the 3rd plural present subjunctive "sie seien" are etymologically identical: both continue MHG sin. The difference between "sein" and "seien" is purely orthographic.Moreover "seien" is normally pronounced just like "sein" ("sei'n Sie so gut..."); the bisyllabic pronunciation of "seien" is spelling-based.

Comment: Your etymological argument sounds plausible (I am just a layman). I heard bisyllabic pronunciation of *seien* too often to attribute it to people pronouncing the spelling, though.